# Fancybox 2 beforeLoad and afterClose not firing to hide/show a div when active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

**I'm trying to use `beforeLoad` and `afterClose` in Fancybox 2.**

I need to hide a flash animation in an iFrame - which is inside the `#elanceiframe` div - while Fancybox is open and showing a portfolio and then show the div again on Fancybox close.

That's because the iFrame doesn't respect z-index in IE and is not "faded out" by Fancybox and is in the foreground alongside the Fancybox images. So I want to `display:none` the `#elanceiframe` div while Fancybox is running.

This is the fancybox init function and it runs the portfolio OK, but beforeLoad and afterClose don't fire.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a[data-fancybox-group=portfolio]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'overlayColor' : '#000',
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.7,
    'beforeLoad' : function(){
       $("#elanceiframe").css('display', 'none');
     },
    'afterClose': function() {
       $("#elanceiframe").css('display','block');
     } 
   });
});
```

Am I using `beforeLoad` and `afterclose` correctly?

Do I need CSS on the `#elanceiframe` div like `display:none` to begin with?

**Edit 12/04/13**

**The above example works fine; I was calling the wrong `div` in the function :(**

Comment: they look good to me. You could even play manipulating the values of the `src` attribute of the `iframe` so your document won't jump as it would with `display: none` http://jsfiddle.net/Nsxcn/ BTW, some of your API options are for fancybox v1.3.x and won't work with v2.x. Check the docs for the right options http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Ah, you're right; I goofed and was calling the wrong div by name. But your idea to hold the size of the frame container was good; it's in a sidebar, so it's less critical. But you should add that as an answer so I can give you credit for that and the newer API options suggestion.

Comment: Answer posted. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options in your code

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    $("#elanceiframe").css('display ', 'none');
},
afterClose: function () {
    $("#elanceiframe").css('display ', 'block ');
}
```

look good to me.

You could even play manipulating the values of the `src` attribute of the *iframe* so your document won't jump as it would with `display: none` like

```
var thesrc;
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function () {
        thesrc = $("#elanceiframe").attr("src");
        $("#elanceiframe").attr("src", "");
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        $("#elanceiframe").attr("src", thesrc);
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsxcn/)**. BTW, some of your API options are for fancybox v1.3.x and won't work with v2.x. Check the docs for the right options : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions! My flash is in a sidebar div so it doesn't impact the layout of the page, but I ended up called other CSS to hold a div's size. But overall, it turns out I was calling the wrong div in my function.